# Finding the max count for each distinct row in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

let's say i have a table as shown below :

```
Genre       | User_id
Animations  |  33
Animations  |  35
Animations  |  33
Thriller    |  39
Thriller    |  35
Thriller    |  35
Thriller    |  35
```

This table shows a movie genre and each user who has reviewed a movie on this genre.(Animations,33) means a user with user_id 33 has rated an animations movie.What i would like to do is find for each genre the user that has rated the **most** movies in this genre(suppose there is only one) and how many are there ratings.

So in the above example solution would be:

```
Animations  |  33 | 2 
Thriller    |  35 | 3
```

How could this be done efficiently using sql?Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also note, you should use [the MD table feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

In statistics, this is called the *mode*.  You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select gu.*
from (select genre, user_id, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by genre order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by genre, user_id
     ) gu
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `Genre` and `User_id` and use `FIRST_VALUE()` and `MAX()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Genre, 
       FIRST_VALUE(User_id) OVER (PARTITION BY Genre ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) User_id,
       MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY Genre) counter
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Genre, User_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7882bdcd4a8c4e93b6625132027fd1b).
Results:

| Genre | User_id | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Animations | 33 | 2 |
| Thriller | 35 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of reviews associated with each user for a given genre, and then find the user who has added the maximum number of reviews:

```
with cte as (select t.genre, t.user_id, count(*) c from test_table t group by t.genre, t.user_id)
select s.genre, s.user_id, s.c total from cte s where s.c = (select max(s1.c) from cte s1 where s1.genre = s.genre);
```

Output:

| genre | user_id | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Animations | 33 | 2 |
| Thriller | 35 | 3 |